# What would be physics of a star totally consisting of electrons?

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, stars

What is the minimum radius and mass (if any) for such a structure to be stable? What is the ultimate future of such structure? Will the electron repellation always be stronger than any gravitational attraction? Even at any density?

Comment: Classically, the repulsive force of electrostatics is greater than the gravitational attraction between electrons at any distance. I can think of no mechanism that would force electrons close enough together than other (short range) phenomena might dominate. What do you think might be in play here?

Comment: @Floris well, there is certain radius (greater than Schwarzshield radius) at which body needs force to hover over the surface of a black hole. This may mean that at certain radius this force may be enough to contain electron's sphere.

Comment: A black hole is hardly a star... And my question remains - how did you get the black hole ("consisting entirely of electrons"). You could imagine a charged black hole but it would be comprised of more than just electrons.

Comment: @Floris i am not talking about exactly BH. Such structure may be greater than a BH.

Comment: And neither was I. But I can think of no force at any distance strong enough to hold electrons together - I believe the electrostatic repulsion will always win. What "glue" are you thinking of?

Comment: @Floris space curvature?

Answer (score 5):

It will never form a stable structure as both electrostatic and gravitation forces decreases at the same rate with distance. And if one dominates at some distance, then it will continue to dominate forever, as the charge to mass ratio of the star will still be same as that of the electron.

Comment: What about general relativity?

Comment: What about it? Are you thinking of a charged black hole?